# Call a specific function when the console program terminates

Tags: c, windows

I'm on windows and I want to call a specific function when the program terminates.

For example:

```
void close_program()
{
    /*do stuff*/
    printf("Goodbye.\n");
}
```

I tried `atexit()` but it only worked on casual and regular exits such as a call to the function `exit()` or when the main returns a value to the OS.

I found out that `HandlerRoutine()` seems like a solution as windows sends a `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` value signal to the process closed by the user (either just close button or end task through task manager). The problem is I tried a really basic piece of code and it said 'undefined reference to `HandlerRoutine`' and that it returned 1.

The piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
         if(HandlerRoutine(CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT))
         {
              printf("Program is being terminated...\n");
         }
     }
     return 0;
}
```

I use MinGW.

Any idea what is the problem might be ?

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683242(v=vs.85).aspx) there is no need for linkage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the MSDN page you linked

> HandlerRoutine is a placeholder for the application-defined function name.

What you need to do is create a callback (of PHANDLER_ROUTINE type) and then use [SetConsoleCtrlHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to register this callback.

Comment: Thanks a bunch ! I succeeded implementing it !

Answer (score 3):

`HandlerRoutine` is the callback function that will be invoked when console will be terminated. It's not the function you have to call but the signature (defined as `HANDLER_ROUTINE`) of your function (that will be invoked by Windows itself):

```
BOOL WINAPI HandlerRoutine(DWORD dwCtrlType);
```

You'll inspect `dwCtrlType` to check for `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` returning (usually) `TRUE`. To attach your function and make it called you have to use `SetConsoleCtrlHandler()` API function, like this:

```
BOOL YourHandler(DWORD dwCtrlType)
{
    if (CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT == dwCtrlType)
    {
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Now you have your function but you instruct Windows to call it:

```
int main()
{
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler((PHANDLER_ROUTINE)YourHandler, TRUE);

    // Do your stuff here

    return 0;
}
```

Please note that you can register more than one handler, they'll be called in chain up to the one that returns `TRUE`. For a complete example just consult [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685049(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Yeah, I've figured that out earlier thanks to Neowizard, thanks for the expanded explanation, though :P

Answer (score 0):

Try including `wincon.h` explicitly. I know there are a number of child header files that are automatically included with `windows.h` but many of these files cannot simply be included by themselves (they are not self-contained), because of dependencies. `wincon.h` is one such child header file used for console services.

Comment: The OP's issue has nothing to do with includes. Why would you suggest this?

Comment: @Neowizard I faced a similar issue while working with `windows.h`. When I explicitly included a child header the undefined reference error was resolved.